# Getting 403 forbidden for Post in chai-http

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, http-status-code-403, rest

I'm getting 403 while trying to run the below piece of code. I'm getting 200 when I tried using axios. What could be the issue?

test.js

```
const chai = require('chai');
const axios = require('axios').default;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-Http');
const { expect } = chai;
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const server = require('../../utils/index');

describe('Post test', done => {
        it("It should POST a new task", (done) => {
            const data = {
                "Request": {
                    "Id": "1000000"
                }
            };
            chai.request(server)
                .post('/dev/1')
                .send(data)
                .end((err, response) => {
                    expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
                    expect(response).to.be.an('object');
                    console.log(result);
                    done();

                });

        });
    });
```

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3ADR.png)